# Cannot render objects in Blender

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

I am quite new to Blender and cannot figure out why the objects are not getting rendered. I have tried a lot of methods from various sites, but it didn't work for me, or maybe I missed some of it. I have enabled a white background for my animation, but upon rendering, I can only see a white image, this is due to the fact that the objects weren't rendered to even reach out to composite node.[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WTxGqZmcckkB2suNQezjwUUHfnKUlYYb/view?usp=sharing) is the link to my `.blend` file

Answer (score 0):

At camera setting, you have too low Clip End distance.. And reduce sun strength, 1000 is pretty much, try 2.. :)